# cpan versus yum install perl-package-name

Tags: apache, perl, cpan, yum

I'm using CentOs7.

What I want to achieve is being able to have my web server use packages installed via CPAN.

I noticed when I install packages via cpan and then include them in my scripts it doesn't work under the httpd user, but it does work under my user.

For the packages to work under the httpd user, I need to do `yum install perl-package-name`.

The problem is the repositories are missing *A LOT* of the packages found in CPAN.

**Manually installing the package like shown bellow has the same effect**

```
# perl Makefile.PL
# make
# make test
# make install
```

Possible clue? ->

On the server when i put @INC i get

```
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd
```

but from ran in the terminal i get

```
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .
```

The terminal and server both appear to be using the same version..

When i download and try to install -> http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/mod_perl-1.31/INSTALL
I get

```
Please tell me where I can find your apache src
[../apache_x.x/src]
```

When i try to install http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8/INSTALL
i get

```
Please provide a full path to 'apxs' executable
```

Should i be installing httpd server from source? and use `--with-perl=`

Comment: As far as I remember, you can start CPAN as your own user, and then the packages will be installed into your home directory. Have you tried starting CPAN as root?

Comment: So basically your saying id have to run CPAN from the httpd user which i cant do. Yeah i tried starting CPAN as root. 

I installed package URL::RegexMatching... then if i do perl "-e use URL::RegexMatching;" It works, but when i add that line in my script and visit mydomain.com/cgi-bin/test.pl the script breaks.

Yet that package isnt in the yum repositories only way i think i can get it is through CPAN

Comment: So you say that after installing the package from CPAN as root, it still does not work as the httpd user?

Comment: exactly, but when installing via yum perl-package-name it works. Problem is i am using packages that are only in CPAN.

Comment: Perhaps i should not be using mod_perl? I cant even get apache to execute scripts without it though :( ?

Comment: Try running `perl -e 'print @INC'` as your own user and as httpd, and see the differences in the include paths.

Comment: OK, a fundamental piece of information, missing from the question, has just emerged: mod_perl. See http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/mod_perl-1.31/cgi_to_mod_perl.pod

Comment: Ok i did `yum remove mod_perl` then i downloaded http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8/INSTALL but am getting `Please provide a full path to 'apxs' executable` idk what that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it all working.

`yum remove mod_perl`

`pico httpd.conf` -> Script aliasing where the scripts reside

Or moving them `/cgi-bin/`

mod_perl and yum's perl packages were the problem. After removing it and modifying httpd.conf it all worked.

**Note** I also installed perl 5.20.1 from source and that seems to have fixed alot of problems i had with Centos7 + CPAN.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your system to use the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), then you'll find a lot more pre-packaged modules.

Comment: I have done this already, is there a way to use perl in httpd without mod_perl?

Even the EPEL repositories have A LOT of missing packages compaired to CPAN.. is there a way i can configure CPAN to work for the httpd user as well as my own? i do alot of dev in perl and i just want httpd to run all my packages like it did in debian. is that possible in centos?

Comment: It's not a case of configuring CPAN to work with the http user. CPAN's default action is to install modules into the standard library directory. Have you changed that? If you let it do its default thing then any user will be able to see the installed modules.

Comment: I have not changed the default and @INC from httpd user and my user have the same value so im confused